# Python googleapiclient for Gsuite Activities & Alerts fetching - filtering & Push mode

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client

I am new to the `googleapiclient` python module, and after a few days of testing the API locally, I have several questions that I couldn't find the answer to in documentation I found:

1. I noticed that the Activities Pull API (`SCOPE='www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly'`, using the [function](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/reports_v1/python/latest/admin_reports_v1.activities.html#list) `googleapiclient.discovery.Resource.activities().list`) has only 2 time related parameters, `startTime` and `endTime`. However I am afraid of loosing information due to delays and backfills, hence wanted to query the API using a `createTime` option, is this possible in any way?
2. In the Alerts API (`SCOPE=www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.alerts`) I did find such an option, by using the `filter` option, which filters on the resulted events; turns out these do have a `createTime` field. Wanted to make sure that by using this I'll indeed get all alerts (e.g by querying in each hour `createTime>=current_timestamp - 1H`.
3. When using the Activities API, I tried to make Push notifications API work (using the [function](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/admin/reports_v1/python/latest/admin_reports_v1.activities.html#watch) `googleapiclient.discovery.Resource.activities().watch`), but didn't find a documentation for the `body` parameter (which should define the output stream) - only found some rough explanations which I couldn't understand. Can someone point me to an example / detailed options for this parameter (e.g. I'd like to create a stream to a local file, is this possible? what other options are there)?
4. I didn't manage to find a similar option for Push in the Alerts API, is there one?

Answer (score 0):

Some answers I found (which you may not find that satisfactory TBH):

1. Didn't find a createTime option, and furthermore I suspect that some of the big SIEM product (Splunk, Devo, Elastic) all use the pull API, with a disclaimer on data loss due to delays on Google's side.
2. don't have anything to add, question still stands.
3. Found some more information about the Pull API for Activities and specifically the `body` parameter, see [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.channel-module.html). This requires a definition of self-owned webhook, so if someone knows a way to bypass this and use a common online webhook resource, I'll be glad to know.
4. I think there isn't an option for pull API for Alerts, but again if someone know otherwise please comment.